# Delphi Comport not getting the complete Data

Tags: delphi, serial-port, delphi-xe, tcomport

I have this code:

```
procedure Tfrm_main.cport_scanningRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
begin
  cport_scanning.ReadStr(data, Count);
  memo3.Text := data;
end;
```

The actual result is:

```
memo3.text := M000000;
```

Then it changed into:

```
memo3.text := 021111D;
```

The expected result:

```
memo3.text := M000000021111D;
```

Answer (score 0):

In future, it would help to indicate what component you're using, especially since TComPort does not come with Delphi.

The answer is because OnRxChar can be called before all data has been received. Your code should read:

```
procedure Tfrm_main.cport_scanningRxChar(Sender: TObject; Count: Integer);
begin
  cport_scanning.ReadStr(data, Count);
  memo3.Text := memo3.Text + data;
end;
```

Comment: Imagine what happens when you'll be scanning the next code (assuming the connected device is some sort of barcode scanner). You should form the code until some terminating sequence is received instead. Some COM port components are able to preset this and do the rest for you (and fire an event when the complete data are received).

Comment: After quick look at [this library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/comport/) I would say that it's the `TComDataPacket` that implements such thing.

Comment: Yes, I was expecting that they'd have either a terminating sequence, or some other indicator